# What is the best way to sanitize a client side form input, using RegExp for the purpose of making an Axios request to a google API

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, constructor, axios

I am trying to create a website utilizing the MERN stack. The website makes a GET request to the Google Books API. What is the best method to sanitize user inputs so that they can be made into variables concatenated to the API URL?

I tried using Regex `replace()` method; however, my console logs don't reflect that it is working.

```
handleFormSubmit = event => {

    event.preventDefault();

    if (this.state.title) {
        const titlesearch = this.state.title.replace(/([()[{*+.$^\\|?])/g, '\\$1')
        const authsearch = this.state.author.replace(/([()[{*+.$^\\|?])/g, '\\$1')

     axios.get("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q="+ titlesearch +"+inauthor:"+ authsearch + "&key=")
            .then(res =>  console.log(res.data))
```

I expected the console.log of `titlesearch` and `authsearch` to return a sanitized string that would be able to be concatenated to the google books URL.

because im noob lvl <10 i cant embed pics so stack provided you with a link [Heres a link to the console logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fki85.png)
Thanks!

Comment: First thing you should do is `console.log(this.state)` and post the resulting object.

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick response! I got  [object, object]

Comment: Helpful. You're going to need to expand upon that. Have the console open when you're doing it, and take a screenshot of the resulting objects.

Comment: i added a picture of the console log and errs

Comment: 400 means unauthorized response. You're not passing any key (API key) to the service.

Comment: i am, but i am keeping it private for security reasons

Comment: Use the `params` property of `axios.get()` to pass your variables instead: https://github.com/axios/axios#example (And earlier, I mentioned 400 was unauthorized. It's actually not. 400 error means there is an issue with your query. If you have axios do the escaping/formatting it *should* work.) Copy/paste the query into your browser, and find out what part of the query is wrong, and go from there.